# How to guarantee concurrent threads dont get the same value in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

Lets say the last row in my orders table is

```
Order_ID      Product
  555          Apple
```

How can I make sure that 2 orders happening at the exact time wont get the same same Order_ID i.e 556 for the next order because this is what's happening to me. My table uses INNODB.

Actually the Order_ID is an auto-increment Field. And I am using the Show Table Status query and using the [Auto-increment] to get the next Order_iD. Any suggestions?

Comment: use table lock in MyISAM and row locking in InnoDB

Comment: Isn't Row Locking implemented by INNODB by default?

Comment: No you have to implement it read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

Answer (score 1):

Define the `Order_ID` column with the [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-auto-increment.html) attribute and let MySQL assign values for you (that you then retrieve by asking the driver for the `last_insert_id` after a successful insertion):

```sql
ALTER TABLE orders MOFIFY Order_ID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Then, to insert records you simply don't provide an `Order_ID` value and it will automatically be assigned:

```sql
INSERT INTO orders (Product) VALUES ('Apple');
```

Comment: @wisdom: Which indeed it is in the question.

Comment: @wisdom I think that order_ID it's a integer value, also you can combine integer + something to keep the unique ID

Comment: ok, by just looking at 555 does not mean that data type in an integer and second ORDER ID Should be a combination of char + int for sound and future safe implementation

Comment: @wisdom: "*i.e 556 for the next order*" - implies that the orders are sequentially numbered integers.  And if one wishes "*for implementation and future safe*" (whatever you mean by that) to have a PK of "*Char + INT*", then store the Char part in a separate column.

Comment: OK I am finally understanding how this works but in my case, I dont have anything to insert to get the last_insert_id. I need the last insert id before inserting anything.

Comment: @ManishPradhan: How can that ever be?  Just wait until you have something to insert before trying to generate an ID.

Comment: @eggyal I need to send the Next Available Order ID as Invoice number to my payment processor. Now whats happening is sometimes, two orders with the same orderid are being sent. As a result I am getting two receipts with the same Invoice number or Order ID as a response from them.

Comment: @ManishPradhan: Surely your payment processor requires more information about the order than merely the order ID?  For example, the total amount of the invoice, the customer's name, etc.?

Comment: @ManishPradhan: And surely some of this information belongs in the `orders` table?

Comment: @ManishPradhan: So then one should first insert those things into the `orders` table, then obtain the `id` of the order, then send it to the payment processor.  I'm struggling to see how you "*don't have anything to insert to get the last_insert_id*"?

Comment: @eggyal I am gonna create a new question with detailed information. Hope that will help. Thanks a lot for your time. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are 'hardcoding' the order_id + 1...

Please use Auto_increment in your table and it will guarantee you it wont be any order_id repeated

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

In your case, make a copy of your table (back-up), alter your table and add an auto_increment then import again

Comment: Actually the Order_ID is an auto-increment Field....??? And I am using the Show Table Status query and using the [Auto-increment] to get the next Order_iD. Any suggestions?

Comment: @ManishPradhan: You could try reading the manual page to which both jcho360 and I have linked in our answers...

Comment: @ManishPradhan if you have an auto increment field then `last_insert_id` is all you need

Comment: @ManishPradhan I didn't get your question, you need an auto_increment to avoid repeated values, you will need use `alter table xxx` to modify the structure and how wisdom said `last_insert_id` will get the last inserted

Comment: OK, I will try the Last Insert ID and see if the problem is solved. Thanks.