# Duplicate ID being sent to the payment processor

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, oscommerce

Here is the scenario. This table Orders has an auto_increment column called orders_id. The table uses InnoDB storage engine. (This is not about inserting new records in the Orders table, its about how to avoid sending duplicate IDs to the processor)

```
orders_id       cust_id       name       address 
100              55           abc        123 street    
101              12           def        456 street
```

For the next order, I calculate the next available Orders_id like so

```
$new_order_id_query = "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE ORDERS";
$result = tep_db_query($new_order_id_query);
$row = tep_db_fetch_array($result);
$new_order_id = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Then I collect other information like name, address, items_ordered... and send it to the payment processor like this

```
102              44           xyz         44 Street
```

The problem is **only** sometimes when there are two or more orders at exactly the same time, I end up sending **two orders with the same orders_id** to the payment processor.

The question is how can I make sure that I am not sending a duplicate Orders_id to the Payment Processor?

I have been suggested to use last_insert_id() which may be right or wrong but I dont know how I can implement it.

I read about Locking Tables - Is that a good idea for a Transaction Environment and InnoDB? If so how can I implement it?

Comment: insert the data into the table, with a pending status, then when it has been processed update it. This way your orders always relate to an actual entry.

Comment: I'm a little confused, if it's auto increment, why are you calculating the id? Are you adding to the orders table first then sending it to the payment processor? If so, then yes use last_insert_id().

Comment: What's this all about? a) You've never used AUTO_INCREMENT before and don't know how to b) You want to reserve an order ID for a future insertion? c) Other

Comment: Note: last_insert_id() will only give the INSERTed ID of that instance of the script. No crossovers and completely safe.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I would say its both a) and b)

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern I am calculating the ID because I need to send it to the Payment Processor before the actual insertion takes place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895692/how-to-guarantee-concurrent-threads-dont-get-the-same-value-in-mysql/12895738#comment17469234_12895738):

1. Collect the name, address, items_ordered, etc.
2. Insert relevant detail into the `orders` table, omitting to provide an `id` (MySQL will automatically generate one for you, guaranteeing its uniqueness through the use of locks).
3. Obtain the generated `id` from MySQL by asking it for `last_insert_id` (the actual function call will depend on your driver).
4. Send to your payment processor.

Comment: OK I understand but whatif the order is rejected by the payment processor? Then That means it should not be in the orders table. But with these steps the order will already be in the Orders Table before evaluation.

Comment: @ManishPradhan: Then you mark it as rejected in the `orders` table, or delete it (as appropriate in your business logic).

Comment: That actually makes sense now, but just out of curiosity is there any way I could get the next ID before any insertion?

Comment: @ManishPradhan: You could lock the table so that no other threads can insert into it, then you would know that the next ID would be yours -- but (for obvious performance reasons) this is generally a very bad idea.

Comment: @eggycal I would like to inform you that the question is not about inserting, I have AUto Increment to make sure I dont have duplicate rows. The question is if I can read the next available ID without allowing concurrent threads to read the same ID. Because now the same NEXT ID is being read by two threads.

Comment: @ManishPradhan: I would like to inform you that `AUTO_INCREMENT` is not intended to be read prior to insertion, but rather to guarantee the uniqueness of any value automatically generated upon insertion of a new record.

Answer (score 0):

auto_increment columns normally do not require manipulation in your code. When you insert new record column defined with auto_increment is automatically incremented.

last_insert_id is used to obtain the value that was assigned to your automatically incremented field within your connection context.

I would not recommend locking table in your case, because you didn't provide any grounds to do so in your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate what the next order ID will be.  Auto increment automatically makes the next ID for you when you insert a row into that table.  That is the whole point of it.

All you need to do is run an insert that puts in all the *other* information into the table, without specifying a value for the auto_increment field.

```
"INSERT INTO Orders (cust_id, name, address) VALUES (55, 'me', 'My House')"
```

If you want to find out what the order ID was of the row you just inserted, simply call last_insert_id() on the query result.  I don't know what `tep_db` is, as it's not something I've used but I think you want the function `tep_db_insert_id()`.

Comment: But I am not doing a insert statement. That comes at the very end. I just need that at the next value at the begining to be sent to the processor.

Answer (score 0):

> I am calculating the ID because I need to send it to the Payment Processor before the actual insertion takes place.

All techniques you've mentioned require that you open a database connection and keep it open between different HTTP requests (while you prevent other scripts instances from using it) so can benefit from a single database session. There's no reliable way to do so.

I haven't worked with osCommerce for ages (I'm surprised it still exists :) but you basically have two possibilities:

- Insert a real order the usual way, but tag it as pending.
- Insert a pre-order in another table (possibly designed by you).

I honestly think you need to save the order before redirecting to payment gateways. If you trust session data you'll lose orders sooner or later; and you'll lose *payed* orders, which is worse.